# How to set Thunderbird leave messages on server in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: thunderbird, mail-server, email-client

I'm trying to set up Thunderbird with secondary mail account and want it to leave messages on server. There was such a feature, at least in Windows earlier, like [this](https://support.tigertech.net/thunderbird-lmos):

[image: https://support.tigertech.net/thunderbird-lmos]

But I can't see those tick box in current setup of the newest Thunderbird in Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: Thunderbird account settings in Ubuntu]

How to set the email client in proper way?

**Update:**

If you want to setup POP protocol in Thunderbird, you may do it manually [this way](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/faq-changing-imap-pop) if you need it.

Comment: On windows you were using POP/SMTP server. On linux you are configured to use IMAP

Comment: @ Jean-Marie The Windows screenshot is taken not from my desktop, this one is from the link beside the image. It shows the possibility to leave messages on server, which is available in both pop and smtp in other mail clients. Fixed disappeared source link.

Comment: Yes, but with IMAP the mails are always kept on the server. The mail client is just a _view_ to the server, not a replication of it.

Comment: @Jean-Marie PerlDuck is right, for differences in these protocols have a look here https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-pop3-and-imap.html , if you want to work with pop3 the best would be to remove your account and when setting it up again make sure you select the pop3 protocol

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshots, note the different server types. IMAP *always* leaves messages on the server, while POP3 can be configured to leave messages on the server or not.

More details: [Email: What’s the Difference Between POP3, IMAP, and Exchange? - How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/99423/email-whats-the-difference-in-pop3-imap-and-exchange/)

Comment: Yes, i've figured it out, but some services do support non-standard extensions letting to emulate leaving messages on server. I't a pity such a useful feature is been excluded from the mail reading standard. Many email clients in Linux nowadays don't support POP3, yet it's desirable method, letting mail stay on the server. I'am tired of choosing multiaccount Linux email client with POP support. And yes, Thunderbird support it, too. Just choose manual configuration.

Comment: @WebComer I don't think you understand. **IMAP already does exactly what you want**, i.e. leaving messages on the server. BTW I do a lot of email support at my job, and I would *highly recommend* using IMAP over POP, even if you only use the email account on one device. It's just too easy to lose emails when using POP.

Comment: Yes, i get it, IMAP already do what i want, yet it was unclear to me in the beginning. It's may be just not my habit to use imap, which at some point in the past seemed slow for me in thebat, so i stopped using it. I've decided to give imap a second chance, as it leave messages at the server by default.